# PHP - Check if word is inside a group of words

Tags: php

I have a group of cities and I want to see if a certain string contains a city from one in the group, if it does it will echo **Yes**.
I was thinking to write all cities in a string, separated by commas.

```
$cities = "'Zimbabue', 'France', 'Sao Paulo'";
```

How can this be achieved ? if not separated by commas, with something else.

Edit=

strpos cant be used, if the string contaning all cities contains "São Paulo" and I try to find Paulo, it will output **true** but should be **false**

Comment: Where's the code you attempted?

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366730/check-if-string-contains-specific-words, seems like that

Comment: I dont think thats works for this case, I want the whole word, using that and trying to find for "São Paulo" if the string is Paulo, it will echo True

Comment: @jundl77 is right. You could use `strpos()` function

Comment: As I said, if the string containing all cities has "Sao Paulo" and I use strpos to find for Paulo, it will output true

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<?php
 $os = array("Mac", "NT", "Irix", "Linux");
 if (in_array("Irix", $os)) {
echo "Got Irix";
  }
  if (in_array("mac", $os)) {
   echo "Got mac";
  }
  ?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Comment: It's not an array. They're all strings can't you see?

Comment: I understand , I consider that he can get the data as array then use it

Comment: Just use `explode` to convert string to array.

Comment: Change your example to suit the question and add  `$s = explode (',',$cities);`

Comment: Using `explode` I could get the results I needed, thanks

Comment: of course you are right if he want to change it from string to array and that means he has output as string. this question maybe vague and what i understand is that he try to get some data in strings like what he mentioned , then check if a certain value is exist,and i suggest to get data as array because it is more easy then search by in array method

Answer (score 3):

You can combine the in_array and explode functions

```
echo ((in_array($searchTerm, explode(",", $cities)))?"Yes":"No");
```

or if you want a more readable version

```
$resultArray = explode(",", $cities);
$result = (in_array($searchTerm, $resultArray);
if ($result) {
   echo "Yes"
} else {
   echo "No";
}
```

Comment: Note that my initial post said is_array instead of in_array. I have corrected this.